# Redefine deep copy/delete/assignment in a simple hierarchy

Tags: c++, assign, delete-operator, deep-copy

I'm learning C++ and I have a some doubts about the deep copy, delete and assignment in this programming exercise; I've this simple hierarchy with an abstract base class:

```
class AudioFile{
    private:
        string title;
        double size;
    public:
        AudioFile(string t, double d): title(t), size(d){}
        virtual AudioFile * clone() = 0;
        virtual bool quality() const = 0;
        string getTitle() const{ return title;}
        double getSize() const{ return size;}
        virtual ~AudioFile(){}
};

class Mp3: public AudioFile{
private:
    int bitRate;
public:
    Mp3(string t, double d, int b): AudioFile(t,d), bitRate(b){}
    virtual Mp3 * clone(){
        Mp3 * t = new Mp3(getTitolo(),getDim(),bitRate);
        return t;
    }
    virtual bool quality() const{
        if(bitRate >= 192) return true;
        else return false;
    }
    int getBitrate() const{ return bitRate;}
};

class WAV: public AudioFile{
    private:
        int freq;       // in kHz
        bool lossless;  
    public:
        WAV(string t, double d, int f, bool l): AudioFile(t,d), freq(f), lossless(l){}
        virtual WAV * clone(){
            WAV * t = new WAV(getTitolo(),getDim(),freq,lossless);
            return t;
        }
        virtual bool quality() const{
            if(freq >= 96) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        int getFreq() const{ return freq;}
        bool isLossless() const{ return lossless;}
};
```

There's also a class called `iZod`; its objects represent the tracks stored in a music player.
In `iZod` class must be a nested class called `Track` which represents a track contained in the player. Each `Track` object has a polymorphic pointer to an `AudioFile`.

Now I have these 4 questions:

1. `Track` constructor must have this form: `Track(AudioFile* f)` and has to build a `Track` object whose pointer has to point to a copy of of the object pointed by `f`. Is my code right?

   I have to redefine the deep copy, deep assign and deep delete and I've done this way but I have some doubts:
2. deep copy, is that correct or have I to delete something?
3. deep assignment, is that correct?
4. deep delete; since in my two derived classes I've no pointers in data types, is it ok to only do the polymorphic-call `fa->~AudioAudio()`?

```
class iZod{
    private:
        class Track{
            private:
                AudioFile* fa;
            public:
                // CONSTRUCTOR
                Track(AudioFile* f){

                    fa = f->clone();
                }
                // DEEP COPY
                Track(const Track& b){
                    fa = b.fa->clone();
                }
                // DEEP ASSIGNMENT
                Track& operator=(const Track& b){
                    if(this != &b){
                        fa->~AudioFile();

                        fa = b.fa->clone();
                    }
                    return *this;
                }
                // DEEP DELETE
                ~Track(){
                    fa->~AudioFile();
                }
        };
        vector<Track> v;
public:
         ...
};
```

Comment: You should Google the "rule of three" or even better "the rule of zero".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did mean that. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call the destructor manually (it's almost never the right thing to do) but since your `AudioFile` member (`fa`) is dynamically allocated using `new`, you should `delete` it.

Replace

```
fa->~AudioFile();
```

with

```
delete fa;
```

in both the assignment and the copy constructor.

It doesn't matter whether the members of `fa` were dynamically allocated, what's important is that `fa` was.